How to Mock location.back() Method Call in Jest for Angular Component Testing?
I'm working on testing an Angular component, specifically the handleConformData method in the ManagePaymentsComponent, using Jest. This method is responsible for setting up confirmation data based on certain conditions. I want to ensure comprehensive test coverage for this method, covering various scenarios including when certain conditions are met or not. I have covered most of the test case but there is one which is not covered. The test coverage when the account value is null or undefined is not covered as shown below.

Ts File
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, LOCALE_ID, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import moment from 'moment';
import { take } from 'rxjs';
import { SaveProduct } from 'src/app/core/interfaces';
import { SaveInvestService } from 'src/app/core/services/save-invest/save-invest.service';
import { StorageService } from 'src/app/core/services/storage/storage.service';
import { BaseInvestComponent } from '../../base-invest.component';
import {
  CreateInvestProductErrorModalComponent,
  InvestProductModalAction,
} from '../../components/create-invest-product-error-modal/create-invest-product-error-modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manage-payments',
  templateUrl: './manage-payments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manage-payments.component.scss'],
})
export class ManagePaymentsComponent extends BaseInvestComponent implements OnInit {
  account: any;
  accounts: any[] = [];
  confirmData = [];
  tryNotifyCount = 0;
  products!: SaveProduct[];
  unavailableDate: string = $localize`:@@loco\:64d080b85197317166074a02:Date-not-available`;

  constructor(
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private localeId: string,
    router: Router,
    modalService: NgbModal,
    saveInvestService: SaveInvestService,
    storageService: StorageService,
    snackbar: MatSnackBar,
    private location: Location
  ) {
    super(snackbar, saveInvestService, storageService, modalService, router);
    this.saveInvestService.currentPageHeader = $localize`:@@loco\:64afcd947dea13249f01fb52:Manage payments`;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.saveInvestService.toggleStepperVisibility(true);
    this.handleConfirmData();
    this.getSavingsProducts();
  }

  openDeleteRecurringPayment() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('invest/recurring-payments/delete');
  }

  private handleConfirmData(): void {
    const product = this.getSelectedProduct();
    this.account = product?.userData || {};
    if (!this.account) {
      this.location.back();
      return;
    }
    this.account.type = this.productType(product.productId);

    this.getRecurrentPaymentNextExecutionDate();

    const sourceAccount: any = this.account?.sourceAccount
      ? {
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:62580d76e922220b5f540f12:Source-account`,
          value: `${this.account?.sourceAccount}`,
          description: this.account?.sourceAccountBalance
            ? $localize`:@@loco\:5f0714017799f92299271aa4:Account-balance` +
              ` ${Number(this.account?.sourceAccountBalance || 0).toLocaleString(undefined, {
                minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                maximumFractionDigits: 2,
              })} ${this.account?.accountCurrency}`
            : undefined,
        }
      : {};

    // Always reset 'userDataEdited'
    this.setSelectedProduct({ ...product, userData: this.account, userDataEdited: undefined });

    if (!this.account.recurring) {
      // Account without SI set
      this.confirmData = [
        sourceAccount,
        {
          titleTag: `Acc. ${this.account.accountNumber}`,
          value: `${this.account?.goalName || this.account.productName}`,
          description: `Balance: ${this.accountBalance(this.account)}`,
        },
      ];
      if (this.account?.type === 'goal') {
        this.confirmData.push({
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:642bc0055b11c37e7d72a392:Target-amount`,
          value: `${Number(this.account?.goalTargetAmount).toLocaleString()} ${
            this.account?.accountCurrency
          }`,
        });
        if (this.account?.targetDate) {
          this.confirmData.push({
            titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:630ef7aa66acdc427a632e82:Info-text-Target-date`,
            value: `${moment(this.account.targetDate).format('ddd DD MMM YYYY')}`,
          });
        }
      }
      this.confirmData.push({
        titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:625cec26795dae3aab31dbd4:Payment option`,
        value: $localize`:@@loco\:642bbf1dc9dcaf153107c328:Manual top up`,
      });
    } else {
      // Account has SI already set
      this.confirmData = [
        this.account?.paymentFrequency
          ? {
              titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:61c08648dfb1585223407592:Payment-Frequency`,
              value: `${this.account?.paymentFrequency}`,
              // description: `Every wednesday`,
            }
          : {},
        sourceAccount,
        {
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:5f0724a875f9bc76f653e575:Account-Balance`,
          value: `${this.accountBalance(this.account)}`,
        },
        {
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:642bbe7599aec22bcf558842:Start-payment-date`,
          value: `${moment(this.account.startDate).format('ddd DD MMM YYYY')}`,
        },
        {
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:642c1f888c27446fa66baaf3:Info-text-End-payment-date`,
          value: `${moment(this.account.endDate).format('ddd DD MMM YYYY')}`,
        },
      ];
      if (
        this.account?.type === 'classic' &&
        this.account?.startDate &&
        this.account?.endDate &&
        this.account?.paymentFrequency
      ) {
        this.confirmData.push({
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:62dfb3755ce92e444e503212:Info-text-Number-of-payments`,
          value: `${this.getNumberOfPayments(
            new Date(this.account?.startDate),
            new Date(this.account?.endDate),
            this.account?.paymentFrequency.toLowerCase()
          )}`,
        });
      }
      if (this.account?.type === 'goal') {
        this.confirmData.push({
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:642bc0055b11c37e7d72a392:Target amount`,
          value: `${Number(
            this.account?.goalTargetAmount || this.account?.targetAmount
          ).toLocaleString()} ${this.account?.accountCurrency}`,
        });
        if (this.account?.targetDate) {
          this.confirmData.push({
            titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:630ef7aa66acdc427a632e82:Target date`,
            value: `${moment(this.account.targetDate).format('DD MMM YYYY')}`,
          });
        }
      }
    }
    this.confirmData = this.confirmData.filter((e) => Object.keys(e).length);
  }

 
}

Test Case
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, LOCALE_ID, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import moment from 'moment';
import { take } from 'rxjs';
import { SaveProduct } from 'src/app/core/interfaces';
import { SaveInvestService } from 'src/app/core/services/save-invest/save-invest.service';
import { StorageService } from 'src/app/core/services/storage/storage.service';
import { BaseInvestComponent } from '../../base-invest.component';
import {
  CreateInvestProductErrorModalComponent,
  InvestProductModalAction,
} from '../../components/create-invest-product-error-modal/create-invest-product-error-modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manage-payments',
  templateUrl: './manage-payments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manage-payments.component.scss'],
})
export class ManagePaymentsComponent extends BaseInvestComponent implements OnInit {
  account: any;
  accounts: any[] = [];
  confirmData = [];
  tryNotifyCount = 0;
  products!: SaveProduct[];
  unavailableDate: string = $localize`:@@loco\:64d080b85197317166074a02:Date-not-available`;

  constructor(
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private localeId: string,
    router: Router,
    modalService: NgbModal,
    saveInvestService: SaveInvestService,
    storageService: StorageService,
    snackbar: MatSnackBar,
    private location: Location
  ) {
    super(snackbar, saveInvestService, storageService, modalService, router);
    this.saveInvestService.currentPageHeader = $localize`:@@loco\:64afcd947dea13249f01fb52:Manage payments`;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.saveInvestService.toggleStepperVisibility(true);
    this.handleConfirmData();
    this.getSavingsProducts();
  }

  openDeleteRecurringPayment() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('invest/recurring-payments/delete');
  }

  private handleConfirmData(): void {
    const product = this.getSelectedProduct();
    this.account = product?.userData || {};
    if (!this.account) {
      this.location.back();
      return;
    }
    this.account.type = this.productType(product.productId);

    this.getRecurrentPaymentNextExecutionDate();

    const sourceAccount: any = this.account?.sourceAccount
      ? {
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:62580d76e922220b5f540f12:Source-account`,
          value: `${this.account?.sourceAccount}`,
          description: this.account?.sourceAccountBalance
            ? $localize`:@@loco\:5f0714017799f92299271aa4:Account-balance` +
              ` ${Number(this.account?.sourceAccountBalance || 0).toLocaleString(undefined, {
                minimumFractionDigits: 2,
                maximumFractionDigits: 2,
              })} ${this.account?.accountCurrency}`
            : undefined,
        }
      : {};

    // Always reset 'userDataEdited'
    this.setSelectedProduct({ ...product, userData: this.account, userDataEdited: undefined });

    if (!this.account.recurring) {
      // Account without SI set
      this.confirmData = [
        sourceAccount,
        {
          titleTag: `Acc. ${this.account.accountNumber}`,
          value: `${this.account?.goalName || this.account.productName}`,
          description: `Balance: ${this.accountBalance(this.account)}`,
        },
      ];
      if (this.account?.type === 'goal') {
        this.confirmData.push({
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:642bc0055b11c37e7d72a392:Target-amount`,
          value: `${Number(this.account?.goalTargetAmount).toLocaleString()} ${
            this.account?.accountCurrency
          }`,
        });
        if (this.account?.targetDate) {
          this.confirmData.push({
            titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:630ef7aa66acdc427a632e82:Info-text-Target-date`,
            value: `${moment(this.account.targetDate).format('ddd DD MMM YYYY')}`,
          });
        }
      }
      this.confirmData.push({
        titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:625cec26795dae3aab31dbd4:Payment option`,
        value: $localize`:@@loco\:642bbf1dc9dcaf153107c328:Manual top up`,
      });
    } else {
      // Account has SI already set
      this.confirmData = [
        this.account?.paymentFrequency
          ? {
              titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:61c08648dfb1585223407592:Payment-Frequency`,
              value: `${this.account?.paymentFrequency}`,
              // description: `Every wednesday`,
            }
          : {},
        sourceAccount,
        {
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:5f0724a875f9bc76f653e575:Account-Balance`,
          value: `${this.accountBalance(this.account)}`,
        },
        {
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:642bbe7599aec22bcf558842:Start-payment-date`,
          value: `${moment(this.account.startDate).format('ddd DD MMM YYYY')}`,
        },
        {
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:642c1f888c27446fa66baaf3:Info-text-End-payment-date`,
          value: `${moment(this.account.endDate).format('ddd DD MMM YYYY')}`,
        },
      ];
      if (
        this.account?.type === 'classic' &&
        this.account?.startDate &&
        this.account?.endDate &&
        this.account?.paymentFrequency
      ) {
        this.confirmData.push({
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:62dfb3755ce92e444e503212:Info-text-Number-of-payments`,
          value: `${this.getNumberOfPayments(
            new Date(this.account?.startDate),
            new Date(this.account?.endDate),
            this.account?.paymentFrequency.toLowerCase()
          )}`,
        });
      }
      if (this.account?.type === 'goal') {
        this.confirmData.push({
          titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:642bc0055b11c37e7d72a392:Target amount`,
          value: `${Number(
            this.account?.goalTargetAmount || this.account?.targetAmount
          ).toLocaleString()} ${this.account?.accountCurrency}`,
        });
        if (this.account?.targetDate) {
          this.confirmData.push({
            titleTag: $localize`:@@loco\:630ef7aa66acdc427a632e82:Target date`,
            value: `${moment(this.account.targetDate).format('DD MMM YYYY')}`,
          });
        }
      }
    }
    this.confirmData = this.confirmData.filter((e) => Object.keys(e).length);
  }

  openAddRecurringPayment() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('invest/recurring-payments/edit/payment-details');
  }

  editRecurringAccount(): void {
    let selectedProduct: any = this.products.find((p) => p?.productId === this.account.productId);
    this.setSelectedProduct(selectedProduct);
    selectedProduct = this.getSelectedProduct();
    selectedProduct.userData = this.account;
    const userData = selectedProduct.userData || {};
    selectedProduct = {
      ...selectedProduct,
      userData,
    };
    this.setSelectedProduct(selectedProduct);
    // console.log(this.getSelectedProduct()); return;
    this.router.navigateByUrl('invest/recurring-payments/edit/payment-details');
  }

  private accountBalance(account: any): string {
    return `${Number(account?.accountBalance || '0').toLocaleString(undefined, {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    })} ${account?.accountCurrency}`;
  }

  recurrentAmount(account: any): string {
    return `${Number(account?.recurrentAmount || '0').toLocaleString(undefined, {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    })} ${account?.accountCurrency}`;
  }

  protected getSavingsProducts(): void {
    this.saveInvestService
      .getSavingsProducts(false, false)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe({
        next: (resp) => {
          if (resp?.statusCode === '00') {
            this.mapProducts(resp.responseObject);
            this.tryNotifyCount = 0;
          } else {
            this.handleProductErrors();
          }
        },
        error: (error) => {
          this.handleProductErrors();
        },
      });
  }

  private mapProducts(data: SaveProduct[]): void {
    this.products = data.map((p: SaveProduct) => {
      const metadata = this.getProductMetadata(p?.productId);
      return {
        productId: p?.productId,
        name: p?.name,
        illustrationLink: p?.illustrationLink,
        minimumDeposits: p?.minimumDeposits,
        shortDescription: p?.shortDescription,
        longDescription: p?.longDescription || [],
        productCategories: p?.productCategories || [],
        slug: metadata?.slug,
        terms: metadata?.terms,
        disabled: metadata?.disabled,
        show: metadata?.show,
        rates: metadata?.rates,
      };
    });
  }

  private handleProductErrors(): any {
    const errOptions = {
      title: $localize`:@@loco\:61fbeddfe4fc547a26382c34:We're sorry`,
      message: $localize`:@@loco\:6214cffea2191e102167dad2:Something went wrong on our side. Please try again.`,
      component: CreateInvestProductErrorModalComponent,
      modal: {
        windowClass: 'invest-create-error-modal',
        centered: true,
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
      },
      options: {
        showCloseButton: true,
        actions: [InvestProductModalAction.tryagain],
        subscription: (action: InvestProductModalAction) => {
          if (action == InvestProductModalAction.tryagain) {
            this.tryNotifyCount++;
            if (this.tryNotifyCount < 3) this.getSavingsProducts();
            else {
              this.tryNotifyCount = 0;
              this.router.navigateByUrl('/invest');
            }
            modal.dismiss();
          } else {
            modal.dismiss();
          }
        },
      },
    };
    this.modalService.dismissAll();
    const modal = this.notifyModal(errOptions);
  }

  name(account: any): string {
    return account?.type === 'goal'
      ? $localize`:@@loco\:5f0725f26e3a005a42063ab3:Goal` + ` - ${account?.goalName}`
      : account.productName;
  }

  private getRecurrentPaymentNextExecutionDate(): void {
    if (
      !this.account?.recurring ||
      // this.account?.nextPaymentDate ||
      (this.account?.type !== 'classic' && this.account?.type !== 'goal')
    )
      return;

    const payload: any[] = [
      {
        savingsAccount: this.account?.accountNumber,
        productId: this.account?.productId,
        customerId: this.account?.cif,
        bankId: this.account?.bankId,
      },
    ];
    this.saveInvestService
      .getRecurrentPaymentNextExecutionDate(payload)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe({
        next: (resp) => {
          if (resp.successful && resp.responseObject?.length)
            this.account = Object.assign(this.account, {
              nextPaymentDate: resp.responseObject[0].nextPaymentDate
                ? `${moment(new Date(resp.responseObject[0].nextPaymentDate)).format(
                    'ddd DD MMM YYYY'
                  )}`
                : '',
            });
        },
      });
  }

  private productType(productId: number): string {
    let type: string;
    switch (productId) {
      case 2:
        type = 'classic';
        break;
      case 3:
        type = 'goal';
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return type;
  }
}

Test Case
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { SaveProduct } from 'src/app/core/interfaces';
import { SaveInvestService, StorageService } from 'src/app/core/services';
import { InvestProductModalAction } from '../../components/create-invest-product-error-modal/create-invest-product-error-modal.component';
import { ManagePaymentsComponent } from './manage-payments.component';

describe('ManagePaymentsComponent', () => {
  let component: ManagePaymentsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ManagePaymentsComponent>;
  let saveInvestService: SaveInvestService;
  let saveInvestServiceMock: jest.SpyInstance;
  let storageServiceMock: StorageService;

  let modalService: NgbModal;

  const mockRouter = { navigate: jest.fn(), navigateByUrl: jest.fn() };

  const mockLocation = { back: jest.fn() };

  const mockModal = {
    dismiss: jest.fn(),
    close: jest.fn(),
    open: jest.fn(),
    dismissAll: jest.fn(),
  };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ManagePaymentsComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule, MatSnackBarModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: NgbModal },
        { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter },
        { provide: Location, useValue: mockLocation },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
    saveInvestService = TestBed.inject(SaveInvestService);
    storageServiceMock = TestBed.inject(StorageService);

    modalService = TestBed.inject(NgbModal);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ManagePaymentsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    jest
      .spyOn(component, 'getSelectedProduct')
      .mockReturnValue({ userData: { accountCurrency: 'USD' } });
    // mock products
    const mockProducts: SaveProduct[] = [
      {
        productId: 1,
        name: 'Product A',
        minimumDeposits: [{ currency: 'USD', minimumAmount: 100 }],
        shortDescription: 'Short description for Product A',
        terms: 'Terms and conditions for Product A',
        disabled: false,
        show: true,
      },
      {
        productId: 2,
        name: 'Product B',
        minimumDeposits: [{ currency: 'EUR', minimumAmount: 50 }],
        shortDescription: 'Short description for Product B',
        terms: 'Terms and conditions for Product B',
        disabled: false,
        show: true,
      },
    ];

    component.products = mockProducts;

    component.account = {
      productId: 2,
      userData: {
        name: 'John Doe',
        age: 30,
      },
    };
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('handleConfirmData', () => {
    it('should navigate back if account is undefined', () => {
      jest.spyOn(component, 'getSelectedProduct').mockReturnValue({});
      const lockationSpy = jest.spyOn(mockLocation, 'back');

      // Mocking this.account to always equal {}
      component['account'] = {};

      component['handleConfirmData']();

      expect(component.account).toEqual({});
      expect(lockationSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      //   expect(component.confirmData.length).toBe(0);
    });

    it('should set confirmData correctly for account without recurring payment (goal)', () => {
      const mockProduct = {
        productId: 3,
        userData: {
          accountNumber: '1234567890',
          goalName: 'My Goal',
          accountBalance: 1000,
          accountCurrency: 'USD',
          goalTargetAmount: 5000,
          targetDate: new Date('2024-12-31'),
          type: 'goal',
        },
      };
      jest.spyOn(component, 'getSelectedProduct').mockReturnValue(mockProduct);
      jest.spyOn(component as any, 'productType').mockReturnValue('goal');
      jest.spyOn(component as any, 'accountBalance').mockReturnValue('1,000.00 USD');

      component['handleConfirmData']();

      expect(component.confirmData).toEqual([
        { titleTag: 'Acc. 1234567890', value: 'My Goal', description: 'Balance: 1,000.00 USD' },
        { titleTag: 'Target-amount', value: '5,000 USD' },
        { titleTag: 'Info-text-Target-date', value: 'Tue 31 Dec 2024' },
        { titleTag: 'Payment option', value: 'Manual top up' },
      ]);
    });

    it('should set confirmData correctly for account without recurring payment (classic)', () => {
      const mockProduct = {
        productId: 2,
        userData: {
          accountNumber: '1234567890',
          productName: 'Classic Account',
          accountBalance: 1000,
          accountCurrency: 'USD',
          type: 'classic',
        },
      };
      jest.spyOn(component, 'getSelectedProduct').mockReturnValue(mockProduct);
      jest.spyOn(component as any, 'productType').mockReturnValue('classic');
      jest.spyOn(component as any, 'accountBalance').mockReturnValue('1,000.00 USD');

      component['handleConfirmData']();

      expect(component.confirmData).toEqual([
        {
          titleTag: 'Acc. 1234567890',
          value: 'Classic Account',
          description: 'Balance: 1,000.00 USD',
        },
        { titleTag: 'Payment option', value: 'Manual top up' },
      ]);
    });

    it('should set confirmData correctly for account with recurring payment (goal)', () => {
      const mockProduct = {
        productId: 3,
        userData: {
          accountNumber: '1234567890',
          goalName: 'My Goal',
          accountBalance: 2000,
          accountCurrency: 'USD',
          recurring: true,
          paymentFrequency: 'Weekly',
          startDate: '2023-01-01',
          endDate: '2023-12-31',
          goalTargetAmount: 10000,
          targetDate: '2024-06-30',
          type: 'goal',
        },
      };
      jest.spyOn(component, 'getSelectedProduct').mockReturnValue(mockProduct);
      jest.spyOn(component as any, 'productType').mockReturnValue('goal');
      jest.spyOn(component as any, 'accountBalance').mockReturnValue('2,000.00 USD');

      component['handleConfirmData']();

      expect(component.confirmData).toEqual([
        { titleTag: 'Payment-Frequency', value: 'Weekly' },
        { titleTag: 'Account-Balance', value: '2,000.00 USD' },
        { titleTag: 'Start-payment-date', value: 'Sun 01 Jan 2023' },
        { titleTag: 'Info-text-End-payment-date', value: 'Sun 31 Dec 2023' },
        { titleTag: 'Target amount', value: '10,000 USD' },
        { titleTag: 'Target date', value: '30 Jun 2024' },
      ]);
    });

    it('should set confirmData correctly for account with recurring payment (classic)', () => {
      const mockProduct = {
        productId: 2,
        userData: {
          accountNumber: '1234567890',
          productName: 'Classic Account',
          accountBalance: 2000,
          accountCurrency: 'USD',
          recurring: true,
          paymentFrequency: 'Monthly',
          startDate: '2023-01-01',
          endDate: '2023-12-31',
          type: 'classic',
        },
      };
      jest.spyOn(component, 'getSelectedProduct').mockReturnValue(mockProduct);
      jest.spyOn(component as any, 'productType').mockReturnValue('classic');
      jest.spyOn(component as any, 'accountBalance').mockReturnValue('2,000.00 USD');
      jest.spyOn(component, 'getNumberOfPayments').mockReturnValue(12);

      component['handleConfirmData']();

      expect(component.confirmData).toEqual([
        { titleTag: 'Payment-Frequency', value: 'Monthly' },
        { titleTag: 'Account-Balance', value: '2,000.00 USD' },
        { titleTag: 'Start-payment-date', value: 'Sun 01 Jan 2023' },
        { titleTag: 'Info-text-End-payment-date', value: 'Sun 31 Dec 2023' },
        { titleTag: 'Info-text-Number-of-payments', value: '12' },
      ]);
    });
  });

});

Output


Please set account to undefined, instead of {}, inside a if condition, {} will evaluate to true so it won't go inside the if!
it('should navigate back if account is undefined', () => {
  jest.spyOn(component, 'getSelectedProduct').mockReturnValue({});
  const lockationSpy = jest.spyOn(component['location'], 'back'); // changed here!

  // Mocking this.account to always equal undefined
  component['account'] = undefined; // null can also be used!

  component['handleConfirmData']();

  expect(component.account).toEqual(undefined);
  expect(lockationSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

Your testcase is fine, I noticed that on the code, you need to do the same above steps for the actual function also!, because the way the code is written, there will never be a scenario where it goes inside the if condition, because, any false condition, will be falling back to {} so the if will never be true!
 private handleConfirmData(): void {
    const product = this.getSelectedProduct();
    this.account = product?.userData; // changed here!
    if (!this.account) {
      this.location.back();
      return;
    }


I had done somthing similar like this and I got the same output after running the tests this part fails:  expect(lockationSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

The locationSpy is never called what could be the problem

Indeed, you are absolutely correct.
